# New scene in Spritekit is not showing anything?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have GameScene, and on a node touched, it goes to a new scene called PlayScene. This is done successfully, but any children nodes I add to PlayScene does not show up. I am, however, able to change the background color in the new scene.

This is what I have in GameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let location = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    let nodeTouched = atPoint(location!)

    if nodeTouched.name == "playButton" {
        print("Play Button Pressed")
        let playScreenTransition = SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 161/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1.0), duration: 0.5)

        self.view?.presentScene(PlayScene(size: screenSize), transition: playScreenTransition)
        vibrateGenLight.impactOccurred()
    }
}
```

And in PlayScene:

```
class PlayScene: SKScene{

    //UI Elements
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    let stickyBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StickyBlock")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("In PlayScene")
        let xy = 0.5;
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: xy, y: xy)

        self.addChild(background)

        self.addChild(stickyBlock)
    }
}
```

And in GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

stickyBlock.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: xy, y: xy)